# I am not 100% sure about what he is saying

Tags: sentence-meaning

Watching and enjoying the [**Kee&Peele sketch**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQkb5Phct1U), there is a line I don't understand what he is saying with full confidence even with the help of the English subtitle.

He(Malcolm X) says from 1:47

> Our people have never resorted to violence, before the white man gave them no choice **but to pay him back in the only currency, he understands!.**

Could anyone help me figure out what he is trying to say?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sentence actually goes "Our people have never resorted to violence before the white **man** gave them no choice but to pay him back in the only currency he understands."

"The white man" (singular) stands in generically for all white people--in the same way that "man is a social animal" means that all humans are social animals--and the singular pronouns "he" and "him" refer back to that singular "man".

The rest of the sentence refers to **[payback](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/payback)**--i.e., revenge--and uses an extended metaphor of money (currency) to make the point that the only response that will be understood is violence.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out the plural part. I had uneasy feeling when I was writing this question. Hmmm...still the last part is hard.

Comment: @Kentaro The idea is that "the white man" only understands one "currency"--which has the dual meaning of either a system of money or an idea that is generally held in society. Because of the monetary implication of currency, it can be linked to the idea of 'payback' which has both a monetary meaning and the revenge meaning. And then revenge is linked to violence.

Comment: @Kentaro There is an implicit which/that: violence is "the only currency [that] he understands."